# Embed Youtube Live chat in

Tags: youtube, stream, livechat

guys.

I tried to embed my live chat in a custom Wordpress page.

I am trying with this code:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=videoID&embed_domain=www.mydomain.com" width="480"></iframe><br />
```

The result is just a blank page...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akdxr.png

Answer (score 1):

Did you note down the domain plain like "yoursite.com"?
Make sure there is no "http" or "www" before your domainname.

Example: "&embed_domain=justmysitedomain.com"